# Finite magma where the only equations are of the form "$t=t$"?

Tags: logic, model-theory, universal-algebra, magma

Does there exist a finite set $S$ with a single binary operation $*$, where the only equational identities that hold are of the form $t=t$ for some term $t$?

Comment: Yes, for example the empty set. And there's one more!

Comment: @diracdeltafunk That's wrong - **every** equation holds in the empty magma (vacuously). Same with the one-element magma.

Comment: Whoops! Thanks for setting me straight

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In fact there is no finite magma which is generic even for one-variable terms.

Suppose $M$ is a finite magma. There are infinitely many one-variable terms but only finitely many functions $M\rightarrow M$; thus, there are distinct one-variable terms $t,s$ such that $t(a)=s(a)$ for all $a\in M$.

Note that it's important that we think about functions on $M$ as a whole rather than just individual elements: for example, for any set of $\vert M\vert+1$ one-variable terms $T$ there will be some $t,s\in T$ and $a\in M$ such that $t(a)=s(a)$, but there need not be distinct terms in $T$ which agree on *all* of $M$.

An interesting question is how many (parameter-free) one-variable terms there can be in a magma of size $n$ up to equality-of-corresponding-operations, as a function of $n$; of course we can get a trivial upper bound of $n^n$ by counting functions, but it's not clear to me that this upper bound is achievable. *(We can also obviously ask the same question for arbitrary arity terms, with trivial upper bound of $n^{(n^{arity})}$, but already the unary case seems nontrivial to me.)*

Comment: Nice question! I suspect arbitrary magmas might be weird enough to encode all $n^n$ unary functions. Not at all convincing evidence: I've checked it for all $n\leq 2$. Maybe you should post this as its own question.

Comment: @AlexKruckman ['Tis done!](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4158959/finite-magmas-representing-all-unary-functions-by-terms)