# Finite magmas representing all unary functions by terms

Tags: abstract-algebra, model-theory, universal-algebra, magma

Say that a magma $\mathcal{M}=(M;*)$ is **unary-rich** iff for every function $f:M\rightarrow M$ there is a (one-variable, parameter-free) term $t_f$ such that $t_f^\mathcal{M}=f$. For example:

- The one-element magma (and the empty magma if we permit such) is trivially unary-rich.
- A bit less trivially, there is a two-element unary-rich magma (in fact exactly 0ne up to isomorphism): namely $M=\{a,b\}$ and $*$ given by $$a*a=b, a*b=a, b*a=a, b*b=b$$ via the terms, $x, xx, (xx)x,$ and $(xx)(xx)$.

My question is:

> Are there unary-rich magmas of every (or at least arbitrarily large) finite cardinality?

Of course every unary-rich magma is finite since there are only countably many terms. Note that if $\vert M\vert=n<\omega$ then $M$ is unary-rich iff $M$ has $n^n$-many distinct one-variable terms up to equality-as-functions.

Already the case of $3$-element magmas seems interesting and [difficult to brute-force](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/47866/28111).

Comment: If I'm not missing anything here, this is the case whenever the magma is primal. And [we know](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4156298/the-ratio-of-finitely-based-magmas-to-all-magmas) that there is an asymptotic proportion of $1/e$ primal magmas among all magmas; hence at least that proportion of unary-rich magmas, and therefore arbitrarily large. For every finite cardinality is another thing...

Comment: @amrsa Ooh, neat - I didn't know about primal algebras! A bit of googling turns up results about primal algebras more complicated than magmas, do you have a citation for the result you mention?

Comment: I've just linked it. Of course it doesn't answer the question completely.

Comment: @amrsa Very neat - although it doesn't fully answer the question, if you post that as an answer I'll upvote it (and accept it if no answer to the harder question appears after a while).

Comment: One of the binary operations on a two element set that makes the associated magma primal is called the Sheffer stroke (it is more commonly known as the NAND operation). I've searched for "n-valued analogues of the Sheffer stroke", but the results are difficult to decipher due to old-fashioned language.

Comment: If you take the operation $\ast$ found in Keith Kearnes answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4159011/rings-with-primal-term-reducts?noredirect=1&lq=1) question and apply the criteria found in his answer to this question, you get a binary operation that gives rise to a primal magma of any cardinality.

Comment: @Eran Doesn't that just work for primes?

Comment: It's only a ring term for primes, but it seems to satisfy the three conditions.

Comment: @Eran Oh yes, silly of me! That's great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[G. Rousseau, Completeness in finite algebras with a single operation, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 18 (1967) 1009-1013](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1967-018-06/S0002-9939-1967-0217002-1/S0002-9939-1967-0217002-1.pdf)

This paper proves that a finite algebra with one $n$-ary operation, $n>1$, is primal iff it has no proper subalgebra, no non-identity automorphism, and no proper nontrivial congruence. Therefore the following are equivalent for a finite algebra with one binary operation:

$\bf A$ is unary-rich.

$\bf A$ is primal.

$\bf A$ has no proper subalgebra, no non-identity automorphism, and no proper nontrivial congruence.

Comment: So actually I already had the ingredients to give a full answer when I wrote mine one! Of course if an algebra is unary-rich then from $a\theta b$ we get $c\theta d$ for every $(c,d)$ using a unary function with $f(a)=c$ and $f(b)=d$, and similar reasoning for subalgebras.

Comment: In conjunction with [Eran's comment above](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4158959/finite-magmas-representing-all-unary-functions-by-terms?noredirect=1#comment8623133_4158959) this fully answers my question, thanks! (@amrsa thanks for your answer too, unfortunately I can only accept one.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber You're welcome. And we agreed from the beginning that what I had to say on the subject wouldn't be a full answer.

Answer (score 6):

From [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4157418/303170) by Eran, we know that the asymptotic proportion of primal magmas among all magmas is $1/e$.

In a primal algebra all operations defined on its carrier set are terms of the algebra, so certainly every primal magma is unary-rich, and it follows that the asymptotic proportion of unary-rich magmas is equal or greater than $1/e$.

In particular, there have to be arbitrarily large ones.
It may however be the case that is not one of every cardinality.

---

**Added.**
From the book "Universal Algebra and Applications in Theoretical Computer Science", by Klaus Denecke and Shelly Wismath, I've got the following results.

> **Proposition 10.5.7**
> (i) Let $\mathbf A$ be a primal algebra. Then
>
> 1. $\mathbf A$ has no proper subalgebras,
> 2. $\mathbf A$ has no non-identical automorphisms,
> 3. $\mathbf A$ is simple, and
> 4. $\mathbf A$ generates an arithmetical variety.
>
> (ii) Every functional complete algebra is simple

and then

> **Theorem 10.5.8**
> For a finite algebra $\mathbf A$ the following propositions are equivalent:
>
> 1. $\mathbf A$ is primal.
> 2. $\mathbf A$ generates an arithmetical variety, has no non-identical automorphisms, has no proper subalgebras and is simple.
> 3. There is a ternary discriminator term which induces a term operation on $\mathbf A$, and the algebra $\mathbf A$ has no proper subalgebras and no non-identical automorphisms.

Here a ternary discriminator term is an operation $t:A^3\to A$ defined by
$$t(x,y,z) =
\begin{cases}
z &\text{ if } x=y,\\
x &\text{otherwise,}
\end{cases}
$$

and a variety is arithmetical iff it is both congruence-distributive and congruence-permutable.

Comment: Do you happen to know if there is a primal $3$-element magma?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Not from the top of my head. I don't know many examples, although we know there are so many

Comment: Incidentally I just noticed that I commented on Eran's answer yesterday - my memory is not good, apparently!

Comment: I had also noticed that. Maybe you're visiting many pages

Comment: It seems that $\mathbb Z_p$ as a ring is primal if $p$ is prime. But perhaps not as a magma. Less operations and we're farther from functional completeness...

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, a primal (even unary-rich) magma with more than one element cannot have any idempotents: if $a*a=a$ then for every term $t$ we get $t(a)=a$, so no function moving $a$ can be represented by a term. So this rules out either the additive or multiplicative magma reducts of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: It's an exercise in Burris and Sankappanavar: IV.7.3. But again, as a ring with $0$ and $1$ as nullary operations

Comment: Sure, I'm just thinking about getting magmas. Actually, here's a variant question. Let $s(x,y)$ be a term in the language of rings (including $0$ and $1$ as nullary functions) and given a ring $R$ let $R_s$ be the magma whose domain is the same as $R$ and whose operation is $s^R$. Which rings $R$ admit a term $s$ such that $R_s$ is primal (or at least unary-rich)? For example, for $R=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ the term $s(x,y)=(x+1)(y+1)$ makes $R_s$ the two-variable magma in my question. I wonder if there are rings with no "primal term reducts" ...

Comment: I think that could well be the topic for another question.

Comment: ['Tis done!](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4159011/rings-with-primal-term-reducts)

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding the definition of "arithmetical variety."

Answer (score 5):

The following is an example of a unary rich magma on $3$ elements I think, the multiplication table is the following:

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 0 0\\
0 2 0 \\
1 0 0 
\end{pmatrix}$

The terms found for each function are as follows:

$ 0\rightarrow 0 \quad 1\rightarrow 0 \quad 2\rightarrow 0 $

$((xx)x)$

$ 0\rightarrow 0 \quad 1\rightarrow 0 \quad 2\rightarrow 1 $

$(x(xx))$

$ 0\rightarrow 0 \quad 1\rightarrow 0 \quad 2\rightarrow 2 $

$((x(xx))(((xx)x)((xx)x)))$

$ 0\rightarrow 0 \quad 1\rightarrow 1 \quad 2\rightarrow 0 $

$((xx)(x(xx)))$

$ 0\rightarrow 0 \quad 1\rightarrow 1 \quad 2\rightarrow 1 $

$((xx)((xx)x))$

$ 0\rightarrow 0 \quad 1\rightarrow 1 \quad 2\rightarrow 2 $

$x$

$ 0\rightarrow 0 \quad 1\rightarrow 2 \quad 2\rightarrow 0 $

$(x((x(xx))(x(xx))))$

$ 0\rightarrow 0 \quad 1\rightarrow 2 \quad 2\rightarrow 1 $

$(x((x(xx))((xx)x)))$

$ 0\rightarrow 0 \quad 1\rightarrow 2 \quad 2\rightarrow 2 $

$(((xx)((xx)x))(((xx)x)((xx)x)))$

$ 0\rightarrow 1 \quad 1\rightarrow 0 \quad 2\rightarrow 0 $

$(x(x(xx)))$

$ 0\rightarrow 1 \quad 1\rightarrow 0 \quad 2\rightarrow 1 $

$(x((xx)x))$

$ 0\rightarrow 1 \quad 1\rightarrow 0 \quad 2\rightarrow 2 $

$((x(xx))((xx)((xx)x)))$

$ 0\rightarrow 1 \quad 1\rightarrow 1 \quad 2\rightarrow 0 $

$((x(xx))((xx)x))$

$ 0\rightarrow 1 \quad 1\rightarrow 1 \quad 2\rightarrow 1 $

$(((xx)x)((xx)x))$

$ 0\rightarrow 1 \quad 1\rightarrow 1 \quad 2\rightarrow 2 $

$((x(xx))(x(xx)))$

$ 0\rightarrow 1 \quad 1\rightarrow 2 \quad 2\rightarrow 0 $

$(xx)$

$ 0\rightarrow 1 \quad 1\rightarrow 2 \quad 2\rightarrow 1 $

$(x((xx)(x(xx))))$

$ 0\rightarrow 1 \quad 1\rightarrow 2 \quad 2\rightarrow 2 $

$(((xx)((xx)x))((xx)((xx)x)))$

$ 0\rightarrow 2 \quad 1\rightarrow 0 \quad 2\rightarrow 0 $

$((xx)((x(xx))(x(xx))))$

$ 0\rightarrow 2 \quad 1\rightarrow 0 \quad 2\rightarrow 1 $

$((xx)(xx))$

$ 0\rightarrow 2 \quad 1\rightarrow 0 \quad 2\rightarrow 2 $

$((x((xx)x))(((xx)x)((xx)x)))$

$ 0\rightarrow 2 \quad 1\rightarrow 1 \quad 2\rightarrow 0 $

$((xx)(x((xx)x)))$

$ 0\rightarrow 2 \quad 1\rightarrow 1 \quad 2\rightarrow 1 $

$((xx)(x(x(xx))))$

$ 0\rightarrow 2 \quad 1\rightarrow 1 \quad 2\rightarrow 2 $

$((x((xx)x))(x((xx)x)))$

$ 0\rightarrow 2 \quad 1\rightarrow 2 \quad 2\rightarrow 0 $

$(((x(xx))(x(xx)))((x(xx))(x(xx))))$

$ 0\rightarrow 2 \quad 1\rightarrow 2 \quad 2\rightarrow 1 $

$(((x(xx))(x(xx)))((x(xx))((xx)x)))$

$ 0\rightarrow 2 \quad 1\rightarrow 2 \quad 2\rightarrow 2 $

$((((xx)x)((xx)x))(((xx)x)((xx)x)))$

I found $1596$ different ones by only checking a small set of terms and going over all the $3^9$ magmas on $0,1,2$.

Comment: Under the supposition that it is indeed unary-rich, this algebra has the following additional interesting feature: since it's not simple, because the congruence $\Theta(0,2)$ is just $\{0,2\}^2\cup\{1\}^2$, it follows that it's not primal, and so we know that there are unary-rich magmas which are not primal (as I suppose it should be expected).

Comment: @amrsa: The algebra in this example is simple.